# How to access MAMP's localhost:8888 from VMWare fusion for WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, vmware, mamp, vmware-fusion

I have VMWAre Fusion running on my MacBook Air running Windows 7. I would like to use this local development environment to test my sites in Internet Explorer. Currently on my Mac and using MAMP, I can access my WordPress site via the following URL: localhost:8888/example. How would I essentially be able to access this local site through Internet Explorer in VMWare Fusion?

Answer (score 0):

Turn Internet Sharing on in System preferences -> Sharing and in navigate to the given IP address. You might need to change your Wordpress site URL to that IP address for everything to work properly.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to which IP address I should be navigation to?

Comment: The one that system preferences gives you when you turn web sharing on. If you specify a port number for Apache in your MAMP settings you have to append that to the IP address. Eg, my address is 10.31.10.130:8888 right now.

Comment: This kind of worked; however, I'm trying to access a local WordPress powered site and and the plage comes out completely broken, i.e. no CSS styling, no images, etc. Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: That is probably because in your Wordpress options you tell the wordpress and the site URL to be at localhost, change that to your IP address and it should be loading CSS and JS files correctly. You might have issues with images you have in posts if their location is also pointing to localhost. Personally I don't bother about this when I do cross browser checks but you could change these locations as well. This would be in within the post, in the image options, in the advanced settings.
I hope to find a solution one day that makes wordpress links relative to fix these problems the correct way.